# Stacked bar graphs in plotly: how to control the order of bars in each stack

Tags: r, plotly

I'm trying to order a stacked bar chart in plotly, but it is not respecting the order I pass it in the data frame.

It is best shown using some mock data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)
cars <- sapply(strsplit(rownames(mtcars), split = " "), "[", i = 1)
dat <- mtcars
dat <- cbind(dat, cars, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
dat <- dat %>% 
         mutate(carb = factor(carb)) %>%
         distinct(cars, carb) %>% 
         select(cars, carb, mpg) %>% 
         arrange(carb, desc(mpg))
plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(data = dat, type = "bar", x = carb, y = mpg, color = cars) %>%  
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

The resulting plot doesn't respect the ordering, I want the cars with the largest mpg stacked at the bottom of each cylinder group.  Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37825559/2761575), the issue is caused by having duplicate values in the column used for color grouping (in this example, `cars`). As indicated already, the ordering of the bars can be remedied by grouping your colors by a column of unique names.  However, doing so will have a couple of undesired side-effects:

1. different model cars from the same manufacturer would be shown with different colors (not what you are after - you want to color by manufacturer)
2. the legend will have more entries in it than you want i.e. one per model of car rather than one per manufacturer.

We can hack our way around this by a) creating the legend from a dummy trace that never gets displayed (`add_trace(type = "bar", x = 0, y = 0...` in the code below), and b) setting the colors for each category manually using the `colors=` argument. I use a rainbow pallette below to show the principle. You may like to select sme more attractive colours yourself.

```
dat$unique.car <- make.unique(as.character(dat$cars))
dat2 <- data.frame(cars=levels(as.factor(dat$cars)),color=rainbow(nlevels(as.factor(dat$cars))))
dat2[] <- lapply(dat2, as.character)
dat$color <- dat2$color[match(dat$cars,dat2$cars)]

plot_ly() %>% 
  add_trace(data=dat2, type = "bar", x = 0, y = 0, color = cars, colors=color, showlegend=T) %>%  
  add_trace(data=dat, type = "bar", x = carb, y = mpg, color = unique.car, colors=color, showlegend=F, marker=list(line=list(color="black", width=1))) %>%  
  layout(barmode = "stack", xaxis = list(range=c(0.4,8.5)))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks @dww.  I updated the example to remove the duplicate values in the grouping column (cars).

Comment: @stu, no, there are still duplicates.  If you eradicate the duplicates, or follow the method above, it will work. Note that `distinct(cars, carb)` will only delete duplicate rows with both these the same.  Not what you want

Comment: yep I see.  thanks @dww I just need to find a decent colour palette.

Answer (score 2):

One way to address this is to give unique names to all models of car and use that in `plotly`, but it's going to make the legend messier and impact the color mapping.  Here are a few options:

```
dat$carsID <- make.unique(as.character(dat$cars))
# dat$carsID <- apply(dat, 1, paste0, collapse = " ") # alternative

plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(data = dat, type = "bar", x = carb, y = mpg, color = carsID) %>%  
  layout(barmode = "stack") 

plot_ly(dat) %>% 
  add_trace(data = dat, type = "bar", x = carb, y = mpg, color = carsID,
            colors = rainbow(length(unique(carsID)))) %>%  
  layout(barmode = "stack")
```

I'll look more tomorrow to see if I can improve the legend and color mapping.

Comment: Also need to ensure that the data is in ascending order i.e. ` arrange(carb, mpg)` instead of   'arrange(carb, desc(mpg))'

Comment: thanks @jota.  Apologies there was a mistake in my sample code, I've removed the duplicate cars within each carb category.  I get the same result.

Comment: @AdamQuek the data is stacked correctly as seen in x1.

Comment: @stu giving unique names to all the car models can get you there, but it will change the legend and you'll have more than one color per car make (i.e. each Toyota will be a different color).  I'll take another look at this tomorrow.

Comment: thanks @Jota, in my real data I have 30 entities in 14 categories so have problems with legend and colour.  It seems like a bug in plotly because ggplot respects the ordering.