# Plotly – sort vertical stacked bar graph by numeric y

Tags: python-3.x, graph, plotly, plotly-dash

I need to be able to sort a stacked bar graph based on the numeric y values in each stack. There seems to be a solution in the R version of Plotly that handles this problem, but I haven't found one for Python yet, or more specifically, Plotly Dash.

Here are two example of how this problem of sorting can be solved in R:

1) [Stacked bar graphs in plotly: how to control the order of bars in each stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37824958/stacked-bar-graphs-in-plotly-how-to-control-the-order-of-bars-in-each-stack?rq=1)

2) [Ordered bars on plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090010/ordered-bars-on-plotly?rq=1)

Here's basic code for a Plotly stacked bar chart:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[20, 14, 23],
    name='SF Zoo'
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
    y=[12, 18, 29],
    name='LA Zoo'
)

data = [trace1, trace2]
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
)

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
py.iplot(fig, filename='stacked-bar')
```

Here's the actual output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXpuf.png

Sorting these bars based on the x axis (categorical) is easy. The only code needed to sort x alphabetically would be:

```
layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    xaxis={'categoryorder': 'category ascending'}
)
```

But is it possible to also sort each stack by numeric y values with Plotly Dash (Python)? Here is what the expected result would be if each stacked bar were sorted such that the lowest y value **within** each stacked bar is at the bottom of bar (regardless of trace):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wEzn.png

Right now it seems like only categories can be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Just switch the order of the traces. Plotly plots the traces, and shows the legend based on the order in which you write the traces.